# Does a model association in rails create a column in that model's table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following the "Getting Started With Rails" guide and I am creating a blog with articles, and comments for each article.

When generating the comment model, we used the following line:

```
$ bin/rails generate model Comment commenter:string body:text article:references
```

Is the part `article:references` the same thing as adding `belongs_to :article` to `comment.rb`? Does this add a column to the table for the comment model?

Comment: That alone itself can't add the column.You should do `rake db:migrate` to get the column in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you generate something that has reference it will create a column called MODEL_NAME_id in your new model:

```
rails g model Comment commenter:string body:text article:references
```

creates this migration:

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.string :commenter
      t.text :body
      t.references :article, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

and the table Comment is like this (my bd is mysql):

```
====== comments =======

commenter   VARCHAR(255)
body        TEXT
article_id  INT(11)
```

PS: You are using the old rails version to learn. Take the latest version to learn and don't waste your time :P

Comment: So if `article:references` is creating a column, then what is `belongs_to :article` doing?

Comment: `belongs_to :article` is for rails understand that this model belongs to the other model. This is not done through reflection as is done with the columns.

Comment: `belongs_to` results in various methods being defined for your model, per the links I just added to my answer.

Comment: I messed up on the rails version because the previous version was used "script/generate" then I looked at the slash that you typed and confused me hahahahahaha I better go to sleep

Answer (score 0):

No. The input to the migration generator affects what migration code is produced which in turn affects what changes are made to the database schema when the migration is run.

The declaration in your model affects what methods can be used to access `article` related fields in your model. The two should be in sync, but they are independent of one another.

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association and http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference for more information.